# Passing data from an Activity that is two Activities away in the hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have my Activity Hierarchy that looks as follows:

Choose Ball -> Choose Background -> Gameplay

Is it directly possible to pass data from Choose Ball to Gameplay? I can easily do it by passing it to Choose Background first but I feel that is a bit convoluted and would involve extra if-else conditions.

Comment: You probably have a 4th activity that is a menu somehow? I would go back to that one each time, maintain the choices there, and start `gameplay` once all the choices are made.

Comment: Why not just save all the current settings into shared preferences?? Shared preferences is essentially a key-value store but since you have to do the choosing sequentially (choose a ball, choose a background, then play) it won't hurt to just persist these choices into shared preferences. This would remove the problem of having to worry about complicated extra if-else conditions as you suggest.

Comment: I will take a look into those options, thanks to both of you! I am a beginning Android programmer so I didn't know about those possible solutions before, but I'll try to incorporate those!